# Mockito doThrow() not acting as I expect

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, stubbing

I'm working on my UnitTests related to a project that uses WebDrivers, WebElements and so on. I got pretty far with mocking connections and everything but there is one problem I'm stuck with.

I got a try block in my class that looks similar to

```
class MyClass {

    myMethod() {
        (...)
        try {
            WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.id(elementId));
            element.click();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            throw new MyException("Unable to locate element!", e);
        }
        (...)
    }
}
```

Now i'm trying to write a testcase where that element was not found

```
class MyTestClass {

    testMyMethod() {
        WebElement mockedElement = Mockito.mock(WebElement.class);
        Mockito.when(mockedWebDriver.findElement(By.id(Mockito.anyString()))).thenReturn(mockedElement);
        Mockito.doThrow(NoSuchElementException.class).when(mockedAllowElement).click();

        try {
            mockedObjectOfMyClass.myMethod()
            Assert.fail();
        } catch (MyException e) {
            Assert.assertTrue(e.getCause() instanceof NoSuchElementException);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that i get the lovely NoSuchElementException instead of the expected MyException:

```
    java.util.NoSuchElementException
    Process finished with exit code -1
```

I checked everything i could think of. During the test hashCodes of all mocked objects in the test method are identical to the ones in the real methods and myMethod runs up to the "element.click()". But the exception is not caught by the catch block.

I must be missing something, I'm quite new to Mockito and UnitTesting in general.

Hopefully I didn't leave out anything important while shortening my logic :).

I'll appreciate any ideas or hints

(edit)

Thank's to all your fast responses, here's the full stack trace:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: this is mine
    at yandex.TokenGeneratorTest.testGetVerificationCodeNoElement(TokenGeneratorTest.java:308)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Also show how all the objects are created. It's strange that the object under test is called mockedObjectOfMyClass. You shouldn't mock the object under test. Also, By.id() is a static method, and you haven't mocked it, so passing anyString() to it won't work as you think it will.

Comment: Is there a chance that the `NoSuchElementException` is thrown from the previous line, that starts `Mockito.when(...)`? Specifically, could `By.id(Mockito.anyString())` throw it? That's my guess.

Comment: You can verify what @yshavit is suggesting by calling `doThrow` with an instance of `NoSuchElementException` initialized with a `String` message.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis without changing the code to throw an exception initialized with a String that was the full stack trace.

Comment: @yshavit i did change the NoSuchElementException that doThrow throws to have a message and it shows in the stack trace, i'll add the whole stack trace to my original post

Comment: What does `mockedWebDriver.findElement` do when `By.id(elementId)` is passed an invalid elementId? As @JBNizet said, passing `Mockito.anyString()` doesn't do what you probably expect it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your ideas.

I just had a "watch out when using alt + enter" moment.

The code works perfectly fine, except my test method threw a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` instead of the `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` my code catches.

Changing this resolved my issue and thanks again for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should re-factor your code to make the testing easier. If its legacy code, then you are on your own.

The method testMyMethod() could ask for webDriver and the exception NoSuchElementException declared to be thrown.

So having something like

```
 class MyTestClass  {

    testMyMethod(WebDriver webDriver) throws NoSuchElementException { 
      ...
    }
```

Now your test could be as below.

```
class MyTestClass {

     @Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
     testMyMethod() {
         WebDriver mockedWebDriver = Mockito.mock(WebDriver.class);
         WebElement mockedElement = Mockito.mock(WebElement.class);
         Mockito.doThrow(NoSuchElementException.class).when(mockedElement).click();

    Mockito.when( mockedWebDriver.findElement( By.id( Mockito.anyString()))).thenReturn( mockedElement);

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.myMethod(mockedWebDriver)

  }
}
```

Also, I highly suspect its during the call to findElement(...) that the exception is thrown as opposed to during the click. But that I guess you are closer to the code.